# Python 2.7 считывает строки в кодировке Unicode

Tags: python, xlrd

В общем я пытаюсь выдернуть строки из файла xls и записываю их в словарь. При обращении к словарю, получаю эти строки в формате unicode.
Пробовал напрямую указывать кодировку

```
streets =[]

excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook('rivals.xls', encoding_override="cp866")
sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)

row_number = sheet.nrows

if row_number > 0:
    for row in range (0, row_number):
        streets.append(str(sheet.row(row)[0]).replace('text:','').replace("'",''))


print streets
```

Не помогает, и с другими кодировками тоже не пашет. Пробовал указывать utf-16le, cp1251, cp1252. Ничего не помогает. Как мне сделать, чтобы записывался нормальный русский текст, а не эта белиберда непонятная, т.к. я потом значения словаря использую для вставки в веб страницы, и мне это всё портит. 
Питон версии 2.7 на линуксе

Дополнил код.

Попробовал сделать через decode

```
if row_number > 0:
    for row in range (0, row_number):
        streets.append(str(sheet.row(row)[0]).replace('text:','').replace("'",'').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Так же не сработало

Вот мой xls файл https://dropmefiles.com/NwGmc
Сделать хочу словарь из него,вида ['Владивосток, 100-летия Владивостока проспект, 153', 'Владивосток, Алеутская улица, 4' и т.д.]

Заметил сейчас такую вещь.

До использования decode полученные данные были с двойными слэшами, после с одинарными

Сделал так:

```
streets =[]

excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook('rivals.xls',  encoding_override="UTF-8")
sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)

row_number = sheet.nrows

if row_number > 0:
    for row in range (0, row_number):
        streets.append( sheet.cell_value(row, 0) +"  " + sheet.cell_value(row, 1))
```

Не помогло

Код с использованием словаря:

```
def add_address_from():

    if len(streets) > 0:
        street = streets[0]
        addr_from.clear()
        addr_from.send_keys(street)
        sleep(2)
        addr_from.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        sleep(2)
        addr_from.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        del streets[0]
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: Пробовали `cp866` ?

Comment: попробовал. ничего не изменилось. По-прежнему вот такое выдает: ['u\\u0412\\u043b\\u0430\\u0434\\u0438\\u0432\\u043e\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u043a, 100-\\u043b\\u0435\\u0442\\u0438\\u044f \\u0412\\u043b\\u0430\\u0434\\u0438\\u0432\\u043e\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0441\\u043f\\u0435\\u043a\\u0442, 153'

Comment: Можете выложить пример Excel файла на какой-нибудь файлообменник и привести в вопросе пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче, все у вас работает нормально, если чуток подправить чтение и вывод:

```
import xlrd

try:
    excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook('rivals.xls',  encoding_override="UTF-8")
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print "Unicode Exception"
    exit();
except:
    print "Exception"
    exit();

sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)

row_number = sheet.nrows

for row in range (0, row_number):
    print sheet.cell_value(row, 0) +"  " + sheet.cell_value(row, 1)
```

метод **sheet.cell_value** (чтение из ячейки) выводит значение как ожидается, то есть с перекодировкой (как указано вторым аргументов функции открытия файла), а вот метод **sheet.row** выводит строку из экселя целиком, без перекодирования (внутрь кода не смотрел, но, видимо, так как строка эксель содержит в том числе и служебные символы это сбивает перекодровщик с толку  и он выдает строку как есть).

Comment: не помогло, только выдает теперь с одинарными слэшами а не с двойными

Comment: Переписал ответ

Comment: не помогло. Добавил код в главном сообщении

Comment: Если выводить принтом, как вы сказали, тогда выводится нормально, но при добавлении словарь и потом если напечатать словарь, опять юникод выводит

Comment: @AlexanderGninenko это нормально, при выводе словаря именно так и должно быть. Объясните, чем вас это не устраивает

Comment: я значения из словаря потом вставляю в поля для ввода на веб страницах с помощью селениума, и мне кракозябры эти там не нужны :)

Comment: Допишите в вопрос ваш вывод со словарем

Comment: Имеете ввиду, что выводится из словаря? Дописал

Comment: Нет, не вывод, а ваш код со словарём и далее

Comment: Этот код есть в самом начале

Comment: Извиняюсь, вы имели ввиду код с использованием словаря. Добавил

Comment: Попробуйте street = streets[0].encode("utf-8")

Comment: Выдало ошибку UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87114/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-alexander-gninenko).